# Cant display Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I writing an android that will display a simple Google map. Everything seem fine.When i run it , it only show a gray grid with Google logo but doesn't display map.

Here is the code

```
       package com.example.myroute;

      import com.google.android.maps.MapView.LayoutParams;  
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.LinearLayout;
      import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
      import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint;
      import com.google.android.maps.MapController;




   public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity 
     {    

MapView mapView;
MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapView);
    LinearLayout zoomLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.zoom);  
    View zoomView = mapView.getZoomControls(); 

    zoomLayout.addView(zoomView, 
        new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    mapView.displayZoomControls(true);


    mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    p = new GeoPoint(
        (int) (lat * 1E6), 
        (int) (lng * 1E6));

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 
    mapView.invalidate();
    mapView.setStreetView(true);
}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    return false;
}
}
```

Here is the manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.myroute"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0.0">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
 <permission
      android:name="com.example.myroute.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.myroute.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
          android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
          android:required="true"/>
<application 
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" 
    android:label="@string/app_name">

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />  

    <activity android:name="com.example.myroute.MapsActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


</application>

</manifest>
```

Here is the Main.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
     android:apiKey="AIzaSyABftaHTCmU-ooh7XH4LMBxLLcFEj5mY_8"
    android:clickable="true"

    />
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
    /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are you running in Emulator or in Real device ?

Comment: @Kedarnath I am running it on a real device.

Comment: Ok, are you using debug keys or you have created another key for creating MAP-KEY ?

Comment: That's the mistake. you need to create new signing key using Keytool

Comment: i use the MD5 fingerprint. to create a API key.

Comment: Of course, but there is two types of signing certificate. Please check my answer's link.

Comment: you should follow this link for map step by step and do not miss any step after that you will be able for work for map.    https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start

Answer (score 2):

Normally gray grid means that you have problem with your API-Key. As you are using debug certificate to generate your API-Key's I suggest you to create a new Signing key using Keytool from sdk.

[Original source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information)

> [image]

Answer (score 2):

The reason you having problems is that you are using an implementation of `Google Maps API V1` probably with a `key` you generated using the `API Console` for `Google Maps API V2`.

I see that because you are using object like `GeoPoints` which become `LatLng` points in API V2, and `MapController` which is not used in API V2.

As `Google Maps API V1` is no longer supported for more then a year now, I suggest you to change you xml layout and java code to `Google Maps API V2` code.

To get you started, here is a blog post I wrote on integrating `Google Maps API V2` in you application:

[Google Maps API V2 Guide](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

In case you haven't produced the key the right way, I suggest you to go over this guide as well and make sure you committed all the step:

[Google Maps API V2 Key](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=403)

Answer (score 1):

In the manifest file add the google Api Key in the application tag  as follows:

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your api key value" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`MapView` for `android v2` isn't like `v1` . So, instead of

```
public class MapsActivity extends MapActivity
```

u should use

```
public class MapsActivity extends Activity
```

or

```
public class MapsActivity extends Fragment
```

and for `API-KEY` u must declare it in `manifest` inside `application tag` and also mention which `google_play_service` version u r using not in `xml file` so remove this `android:apiKey="AIzaSyABftaHTCmU-ooh7XH4LMBxLLcFEj5mY_8"` from xml and add this in `manifest`

```
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
      android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
      android:value="your api key value" />
```

from my point of view its better to use `MapFragment` instead of `MapView`
[Tutorial for How to use Mapview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) and for MapFragment [Tutorial for How to use MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

*code snippet of using `MapView`*

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView m;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // inflat and return the layout
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        m = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        m.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        m.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        m.onPause();
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        m.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        m.onLowMemory();
    }
}
```

*xml file*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapView" />
```

> android:minSdkVersion="7" should be android:minSdkVersion="8" u can
>   google it for why? by doing this if u don't see the map then there is
>   some problem with `API-KEY` make sure u have use ur computer's SHA-1
>   fingerprint;com.example.myroute to generate `API-KEY` for ur map.If ur
>   google play service's version is mismatched u can't see the map too.